# Material 3 Top Bar container color not change on scroll

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The top app bar container color not change on scroll, the color keep the same. Working with XML views it works fine, but compose doesn't.

If is a bug or the featured was not ported for compose yet, but if ins't a bug, i'm miss something in the code?

I'm using version 1.0.1 of the material 3 library.

Sample code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            val uiController = rememberSystemUiController()
            uiController.setStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent)
            MyApplication5Theme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            TopAppBar(
                                title = { Text("k") },
                                modifier = Modifier.statusBarsPadding(),
                            )
                        }
                    ) {
                        LazyColumn(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(it)
                        ) {
                            items((1..100).toList()) {
                                Text(it.toString(), modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried create a simple layout with a top app bar and a lazy column, i expected top app bar container color changes on scroll of the lazy column, but the color keep the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TopAppBar` composable has a `scrollBehavior` argument, which is `null` be default. If you leave it `null`, it will not react to scroll events, you have to connect it with your scrollable component. You can do that like this:

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topBar = { TopAppBar(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior, ...) },
) { LazyColumn() {} }
```

Comment: Wouldn't TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState()) be better?

Comment: That's the default value, no reason to explicitly provide it unless you want to change the default values of `rememberTopAppBarState`.

Comment: Strange that we need to write this code for a behavior that's supposed to be the default one when scrolling a list under an appbar.